# How hide selected element in select?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I hide the selected element in a select?

See picture:

**Picture one**
[image: Picture one]

**Picture two**
[image: Picture two]

How can I do this?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Maybe `display: hidden`? http://jsfiddle.net/CPvXC/ Not sure how cross-browser this is.

Comment: Something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/TJFzh/ ?

Comment: you need the checked pseudoclass in css, no js needed for this, see my answer below

Comment: My two cents: This is a silly idea and will create more usability problems than it solves. People have an expectation about how a select box works. Why mess with it?

Comment: oh) big thanks all answers. its best drive for help) THANKS!

Comment: @KevinBoucher you dont right. i ask becose it need my peoples..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you dont need javascript for this, but only one line of css:

```
option:checked { display: none; }
```

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/kJckW/2/

Comment: This `select` box is not usable.

Comment: @DudeSolutions I guess you're the upvoter? Did you try using the select box in the referenced fiddle? Try selecting a different option than the default.

Comment: maybe exclude firefox from this using @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  option:checked {
     display:block;
  }
}   hacky, but will prevent problems.

Answer (score 1):

This would all depend on your mark-up.

```
$("#select_id option[value='foo']").remove();
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJckW/1/).

Comment: @LeoLoki - it would be helpful if your questions provided more detail. Even some code samples

Answer (score 1):

Well you didn't post any markup or code, but I'll make some for you:

```
<select id="shirts">
   <option>blue shirt</option>
</select>

$("#shirts").on('change', function () {
   //Remove the hidden input and restore the removed value
   if ($("#trueshirt").length) {
      $(this).append("<option>" + $("#trueshirt").val() + "</option>");
      $("#trueshirt").remove();
   }

   //get the selected value
   var val = $(this).val();

   //Remove the option as requested (simply hiding it is incompatible with
   //some browsers)
   $("option:selected", this).remove();

   //Create hidden input to keep the value
   $("<input>").val(val).attr({'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'shirt', id: 'trueshirt'})
      .insertAfter(this);
});
```